# select on the non-existing column 'name' returns tupels (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, select

When I selected accidentally the non-existing column 'name' from a table the statement returned the record as a tuple (please see the example below).  This worked with server version 8.4.3 (not with 8.2).  The client was 8.4.4.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl 
  ( foo varchar(8), bar varchar(8), baz varchar(8) )
ON COMMIT DROP;

COPY tmp_tbl ( foo, bar, baz) 
FROM stdin
WITH DELIMITER ',';
justus,peter,bob
langly,frohike,byers
alpha,beta,gamma
\.

-- SELECT * from tmp_tbl;
SELECT tmp_tbl.name from tmp_tbl;

END;
```

The output was

```
          name          
------------------------
 (justus,peter,bob)
 (langly,frohike,byers)
 (alpha,beta,gamma)
(3 rows)
```

and not an error, as I expected.

Could you show me where I can read about this feature in the PostgrSQL documentation?  I couldn't find anything and using google to search for 'select', 'name'  etc. was not really helpful.

Thanks for you answer in advance!
k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread on the PostgreSQL mailing list:

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2010-02/msg01038.php

Essentially `foo.name` is "translated" to `name(foo)`

I agree this is confusing.